# array list item get repeated every time when i run my app

Tags: android, arraylist, duplicates

Hi i face a problem my arraylist view item get duplicated every time when i run app. 
I store all the item of arraylistview in my string.xml file

```
 public class Button_mak extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
final Context context = this;
public static ArrayList<Advertisement> ads = new ArrayList<Advertisement>();
```

private void populateAdsFromMetadata() {

```
            String [] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title);
            String [] detailedMessages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.detailed_message);
            String [] ownerName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.owner_name);
            String [] ownerEmail = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.owner_email);
            String [] price = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.price);
            String [] image = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.images);
            String [] id = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.id);

            for(int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
                Advertisement ad1 = new Advertisement(titles[i],
                        detailedMessages[i], ownerName[i], 
                        ownerEmail[i], image[i], Integer.parseInt(price[i]), Integer.parseInt(id[i]));  
                ads.add(ad1);
            }

        }
```

Comment: this is expected behaviour unless you a persisting this information to a data store or sharedPreferences.  Where are you calling PopulateAdsFromMetaData()?  OnResume is called unless you destroy the activity.

Comment: i call add from string.xml.And PopulateAdsFrom call in same activity where array list is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep `public static ArrayList<Advertisement> ads`to avoid recreating the list everytime..Instead you can clear the list before adding new set of elements.Something like below:

```
 ads.clear();
for(int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
            Advertisement ad1 = new Advertisement(titles[i],
                    detailedMessages[i], ownerName[i], 
                    ownerEmail[i], image[i], Integer.parseInt(price[i]),       Integer.parseInt(id[i]));  
            ads.add(ad1);
        }
```

Comment: Ooo waoo cool its gr8t. Can u plz tell me how i store add permanently in my listview. Forexampl if i post new add it appear in my listview but when i again login to device my add is disappear...........

Comment: use sqlite database to store data persistently

Comment: i already use this link
http://techblogon.com/android-login-registration-screen-with-sqlite-database-example/ 
to create user id and password now what i should do to store my list view item permanently i search many link but those were not help full:-(

Comment: refer this link:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html